# more methods for before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is possible set 2 methods on before_validation in a model?

```
before_validation :elaborate
before_validation :download_remote_data, :if => :data_url_provided?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, your code is fine. Just have in mind that elaborate method is going to be executed first (since it's registered before the download_remote_data method).

Comment: Good catch with the conditional callback. I've removed my answer as it doesn't add anything new.

Answer (score 4):

That is certainly valid.  You can add as many `before_validation` calls as you need.